# Append on responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I moved my element from `.copyfilterArea` to `.copyfilter .container-margin` to responsive, if my resolution is less than 768px then move my element.. it's okay so far, function is working properly, but if my resolution is bigger than 768px then put my div back to original location. only this section I couldn't do, how can I change my code to put the div back to the original location ? I tried append but nothing change

```js
 $(function () {
    var flag;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
        console.log(bodyWidth)
        if (flag !== false && bodyWidth < 768) {
            //move the element to new location
            $('.copyFilterArea').appendTo('.copyFilter .container-margin');
            flag = false;
        } else if (flag !== true && bodyWidth >= 768) {
          //put it back to original location
            console.log('more')
            flag = true;
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

```css
.copyFilter .container-margin{
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="copyFilterArea">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo itaque voluptates quasi incidunt atque aliquam neque ducimus quibusdam quo fuga provident blanditiis sint saepe, culpa ipsam a quae magnam pariatur quidem ad. Numquam repudiandae rerum aliquid, reiciendis minus ipsa nostrum esse quam deserunt in! Odit cum incidunt molestias tempora accusamus doloribus, quidem saepe, iusto assumenda ad. Consequuntur voluptatibus earum voluptate veniam aspernatur, sapiente, molestias, voluptates officia perspiciatis nesciunt ducimus maiores excepturi iure ratione magnam eligendi, quia quisquam porro. Nobis explicabo, voluptatibus nulla a delectus aut dolorum excepturi distinctio. Similique veniam maxime fugiat deleniti ipsam autem in itaque at magni blanditiis.</p>
</div>


<div class="copyFilter">
  <div class="container-margin">
    <h1>COPY CONTENT WİLL BE HERE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't see you putting it back  ,where is your append?

Comment: when it isn't work I remove it from my code

Comment: $('.copyFilter .container-margin').appendTo('.copyFilterArea'); it was like that

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prependTo` to place the text in the initial state:

```js
$(function () {
    var flag;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
        console.log(bodyWidth)
        if (flag !== false && bodyWidth < 768) {
            //move the element to new location
            $('.copyFilterArea').appendTo('.copyFilter .container-margin');
            flag = false;
        } else if (flag !== true && bodyWidth >= 768) {
          //put it back to original location
           $('.copyFilterArea').prependTo('.copyFilter .container-margin');
            console.log('more')
            flag = true;
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

```css
.copyFilter .container-margin{
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="copyFilterArea">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo itaque voluptates quasi incidunt atque aliquam neque ducimus quibusdam quo fuga provident blanditiis sint saepe, culpa ipsam a quae magnam pariatur quidem ad. Numquam repudiandae rerum aliquid, reiciendis minus ipsa nostrum esse quam deserunt in! Odit cum incidunt molestias tempora accusamus doloribus, quidem saepe, iusto assumenda ad. Consequuntur voluptatibus earum voluptate veniam aspernatur, sapiente, molestias, voluptates officia perspiciatis nesciunt ducimus maiores excepturi iure ratione magnam eligendi, quia quisquam porro. Nobis explicabo, voluptatibus nulla a delectus aut dolorum excepturi distinctio. Similique veniam maxime fugiat deleniti ipsam autem in itaque at magni blanditiis.</p>
</div>


<div class="copyFilter">
  <div class="container-margin">
    <h1>COPY CONTENT WİLL BE HERE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you facing any issue with append and remove particular element in DOM at runtime then alternative you can handle it with hide/show logic where your element duplicate as below:

```js
$(function () {
    var flag;
    $(".subFilterArea").hide();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
        console.log(bodyWidth)
        if (flag !== false && bodyWidth < 768) {
            //move the element to new location
            $(".mainFilterArea").hide();
            $(".subFilterArea").show();
            flag = false;
        } else if (flag !== true && bodyWidth >= 768) {
          //put it back to original location
            $(".mainFilterArea").show();
            $(".subFilterArea").hide();
            flag = true;
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

```css
.copyFilter .container-margin{
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="copyFilterArea mainFilterArea">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo itaque voluptates quasi incidunt atque aliquam neque ducimus quibusdam quo fuga provident blanditiis sint saepe, culpa ipsam a quae magnam pariatur quidem ad. Numquam repudiandae rerum aliquid, reiciendis minus ipsa nostrum esse quam deserunt in! Odit cum incidunt molestias tempora accusamus doloribus, quidem saepe, iusto assumenda ad. Consequuntur voluptatibus earum voluptate veniam aspernatur, sapiente, molestias, voluptates officia perspiciatis nesciunt ducimus maiores excepturi iure ratione magnam eligendi, quia quisquam porro. Nobis explicabo, voluptatibus nulla a delectus aut dolorum excepturi distinctio. Similique veniam maxime fugiat deleniti ipsam autem in itaque at magni blanditiis.</p>
</div>


<div class="copyFilter">
  <div class="container-margin">
    <h1>COPY CONTENT WİLL BE HERE</h1>
    <div class="copyFilterArea subFilterArea">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo itaque voluptates quasi incidunt atque aliquam neque ducimus quibusdam quo fuga provident blanditiis sint saepe, culpa ipsam a quae magnam pariatur quidem ad. Numquam repudiandae rerum aliquid, reiciendis minus ipsa nostrum esse quam deserunt in! Odit cum incidunt molestias tempora accusamus doloribus, quidem saepe, iusto assumenda ad. Consequuntur voluptatibus earum voluptate veniam aspernatur, sapiente, molestias, voluptates officia perspiciatis nesciunt ducimus maiores excepturi iure ratione magnam eligendi, quia quisquam porro. Nobis explicabo, voluptatibus nulla a delectus aut dolorum excepturi distinctio. Similique veniam maxime fugiat deleniti ipsam autem in itaque at magni blanditiis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @madalin has better solution, I have just give you an alternate

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  var flag;
  var $copyFilterArea = $('.copyFilterArea')
  $(window).resize(function () {
      var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
      console.log(bodyWidth)
      if (flag !== false && bodyWidth < 768) {
          //move the element to new location
          $copyFilterArea.appendTo($('.copyFilter .container-margin'));
          flag = false;
      } else if (flag !== true && bodyWidth >= 768) {
        //put it back to original location
          if($("body").children(".copyFilterArea").length<=0){
            $copyFilterArea.prependTo($('body'))
          }
          console.log('more')
          flag = true;
      }
  }).resize();
 });
```